# MySQL Convert JSON column to array and get pages

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, mysql-json

It's pretty difficult to pick a title, I'm sorry for that!

What I have for a database structure is the following columns:

pages

- id (int)
- url (string)
- content (string)
- created_at (timestamp)

groups

- id (int)
- related_page_ids (json)
- domain_id (int)
- created_at (timestamp)

What I want to achieve is to retrieve all groups by a selected domain ID and then retrieve all the related_pages with it. If I should write it in ugly PHP and MySQL:

```
$groups = SELECT * FROM groups WHERE domain_id = 1;
    
foreach($groups as $group){
    $pages = SELECT * FROM pages WHERE IN id = implode($group['related_page_ids']);
}
```

I hope that you understand my goals with the ugly example.

Comment: Please provide sample data. This also is likely why storing delimited data is a bad choice. This would be a simple task with a `pages_to_group` table.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you decide to use JSON for the related_page_ids, instead of the standard normalized solution, which should be a third table for the many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `JSON_TABLE` (MySQL 8 / MariaDB 10.6) it can be done with that in a single query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pages 
 WHERE id IN (
  SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(
    (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(related_page_ids) FROM groups WHERE domain_id=1),
    '$[*][*]' columns(rel_id INTEGER path '$')) AS jt );
```

The column needs to actually be of type `JSON` (not varchar) for this to work.